# Способ перемещения персонажа JavaScript в онлайн игре

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, canvas

Пишу небольшую онлайн игру. Уже две недели стараюсь найти оптимальный способ перемещения персонажа.

1. Изначально, каждый персонаж являлся div'ом, отправлял на сервер координаты клика мыши, после чего сервер отправлял всем клиентам эти координаты и персонаж (div) с помощью transition смещался на полученные координаты.
2. После чего встретил в интернете казалось бы хороший вариант, 60 раз в секунду отправлять на сервер координаты персонажа и с помощью джойстика их изменять, то есть нажата keyCode 65 (клавиша "A") - на сервер идет запрос и на его же стороне прибавляется += 5, сервер в свою очередь 60 раз в секунду всем подключенным клиентам рассылал обновленные координаты игроков. Клиент в ответ на сообщение сервера на канвасе отрисовывал новые положения игроков. Способ вполне хороший, если бы не одно НО, которое окончательно убило желание продолжать его использовать: 
   Когда подключено более 5-10 клиентов - сервер уже не справляется каждому из них отправлять по 60 запросов в секунду и каждый клиент начинает буквально виснуть.

На данный момент, в голове прокручивается мысль о том, чтобы перемещать каждого игрока непосредственно на стороне клиента, на сервер отправляется лишь информация о том что игрок начал движение, сервер ее принимает и рассылает всем клиентам, после чего каждый клиент перемещает персонажа с каким-то например ID.
Но, не совсем понимаю как плавно переместить персонажа, зная лишь его конечные координаты. Создаются действительно большие вопросы, на которые самостоятельно ответить не могу.

Может быть здесь кто-нибудь имел подобный опыт, сталкивался с похожей проблемой. Будьте добры, поделитесь своим мнением касательно этого.

Comment: интерполяция + отправлять данные только когда что-то приозошло. А сервер пусть 30 раз в секунду отправляет данные, 60 это уж прям оч много

Comment: Сокращал даже до 20, нагрузка спадает практически незначительно. Данные отправляются когда персонаж начинает движение. На этом моя оптимизация оказывается  в безысходном положении. Когда на сервере менее 10 клиентов - всё прекрасно. Но, когда количество превышает это число - начинается слайд-шоу.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКалайда а данные каким образом Вы передаете?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q В виде строки, на сервере/клиенте формирую со строки массив. Мне кажется, в данном алгоритме лишнее отправлять ежесекундно информацию пользователям, нужно получить запрос от клиента на перемещение и отправить всем подключенным пользователям ее, а далее каждый уже на стороне клиента перемещает персонажа. Но, как сделать плавное перемещение с исходной точки в указанную - вот в этом скорее и заключается мой вопрос. Думаю, сравнивать что-ли, if (данная позиция не равняется указанной) {+1 к координатам}, но ведь канвас не хранит данные, а лишь перерисовывает их.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКалайда транспорт websocket?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Да.

Comment: Вот, хотел предложить вариант, который предложил This Man. У Вас игра типа Герои 3 или Контр-Страйк?

Comment: @Дмытрык Добрый вечер! По системе - как Контр-Страйк. Даже представить не могу с помощью чего я могу оптимизировать, на данный момент действительно все очень плохо. Уменьшил количество запросов вплоть до 20, на пару клиентов выдерживает больше, но уже заметны рывки при движении, так как 20 обновлений в секунду это все же мало. Поэтому думаю, как же мне перемещать персонажей на стороне клиента, а не на стороне сервера, чтобы сервер лишь одним сообщением давал "команду" всем пользователям на перемещение определенного игрока.

Comment: Я такое не реализовывать, но мысли так: допустим, есть несколько персонажей....двигается только 1 из них.... в таким случае, зачем всем ждать инфу с сервера? Инфа нужна, только в том случае, если произошли ка4ие-то изменения: другой и7рок начал движение, первый поменял направление и т.д

Comment: .....+ где-то читал, что в таких случаях используется алгоритм предсказания событий. Если найду  ссылку, скину

Comment: Но изменения даже при онлайне в 10 человек конечно же будут постоянно, достаточно одному пользователю начать движение и сервер опять начнет плохо рабоатать от большого количества передаваемой информации.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/182678/

Comment: @Дмытрык Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: В смысле, помогло? Уже все реализовали?)

Comment: @Дмытрык от столь значительных "рывков" при существенном количестве игроков на сервере избавиться удалось)